# How to check and calculate values in excal from multiple table

Tags: excel, excel-formula, subtraction

Is there any way to check and subtract same type of values from one table to another in `Excel`, like as showed in below screenshot I have three tables Buy, Sell and Available. I want to calculate Available table according to Buy and Sell table.

Example:-  I purchased 10 ABC at 10 price and i sell twice once 5 at price of 2 and then 4 at price of 2, so in Available table under Amount column it should show 3 [10-(5+2)=3].

Is there any formula or any trick to do this in excel?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image clearly shows the formula that you need to enter. Here I have made absolute range with upper limit as 99999. You can increase this range as your data exceeds 99999.

[image: Screenshot with Formula]

Comment: Thank you for your help...! I need one more help how I can ignore `#VALUE!` & `#N/A` while using SUM or any function.

Comment: you can use iferror function to get a particular value if error occurs source https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/how-to-correct-a-value-error-15e1b616-fbf2-4147-9c0b-0a11a20e409e?ui=en-US&rs=en-IN&ad=IN

Answer (score 1):

Use the SUMIF function in Excel. The screenshot shows how you could apply it.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help...! I need one more help how I can ignore `#VALUE!` & `#N/A` while using `SUM` or any function.

Comment: What you could do is use IFERROR in cells D2, F2 and F3 in the example above. The first argument of that function asks you for the value to display, the second argument should be the value that substitutes the first argument in case it returns #VALUE! or #N/A. The second argument could be '0', which is a valid value for SUMIF.